# Net::SFTP::StatusException (5, "bad message") While Sending Chunks Of A Large File:

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sftp, fog

**Short Version:**

Sending files from S3 in **more than one chunk** to **SFTP** server fails with a `Net::SFTP::StatusException (5, "bad message")` error.

**Long Version:**

I'm trying to send a large file from my **RoR** application to a customer's **SFTP** server.

I'm using `Fog::Storage` as I'm reading the file from my `S3` server.

Here is my example code:

```
file_paths = get_file_names()
Net::SFTP.start(sftp_domain, sftp_user, :password => sftp_password) do |sftp|
  file_paths.each do |file_to_upload|
    filename = nil
    if Rails.env == "production"
      filename = file_to_upload.file.path.split("/").last
                            
      # Create S3 Connection:
      connection = Fog::Storage.new(provider: 'AWS'...)

      # Find root directory:
      bucket = connection.directories.get(ENV['MY_S3'])

      # Send all files in directory, chunk-by-chunk:
      sftp.file.open(sftp_folder + "/" + filename, "w") do |sftp_file|
        bucket.files.get(file_to_upload.file.path) do |chunk|
          sftp_file.write(chunk)
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

**ONLY** when a single file exceeds the default chunk-size, I get the following error:

```
Excon::Error::Socket: Net::SFTP::StatusException (5, "bad message") (Net::SFTP::StatusException)
```

**More details:**

- Using rails 4.2.5.1.
- Using ruby 2.3.4p301 (2017-03-30 revision 58214) [aarch64-linux]
- Gem locked at net-sftp (3.0.0) and net-ssh (6.1.0).
- Files that are small enough to be sent in **one** chunk - are sent correctly.

**What I tried:**

- enforcing an encoding didn't work (same error).
- reading the large file in one chunk did not work (memory error).

I will be happy to add more details as needed, sorry if I missed something!

Thanks in advance to everyone!

Comment: Always when you run into problems like this you should start by eliminating as many moving parts as possible. S3 is kind of a black box here. I would eliminate it, eliminate Rails, and make a simple test script that uses a large local file instead and see if you can write that in more than one chunk or not. It could be a remote server incompatibility. What about the file name? How is that encoded? Simple name, complex name, UTF-8 name? Eliminate as many unknowns as you can to narrow down why and where the error occurs. Just use a simple `.rb` file to test. No Rails, no S3. Only local file.

Comment: Could also be a bug in Ruby SFTP. But you need to eliminate the other variables first.

Comment: One more idea. Try `write!` instead of `write`. The plain `write` is async, and if you write in a loop perhaps SFTP doesn't like a new async request while the previous one is processing. Better use `write!` which waits for the operation to finish.

Comment: @Casper - Excon::Error::Socket: undefined method `write!' for #<Net::SFTP::Operations::File:0x00000044784d00>

Comment: @Casper as per the above exception, I can’t use “write!”...

Comment: Yeah it's OK. I notice `Net::SFTP::Operations::File.write` calls `write!` internally already. So the problem must be somewhere else. I run out of ideas for now since there is not much more information to go on.